# How would you change this Akka Streams example to get the materialized value Future[ServerBinding]?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

The second example at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-io.html is the following.  I added definitions of `host` & `port`.

```
  val host = "localhost"
  val port = 4444
  val connections: Source[IncomingConnection, Future[ServerBinding]] =
    Tcp().bind(host, port)

  connections runForeach { (connection: IncomingConnection) =>
    println(s"New connection from: ${connection.remoteAddress}")

    val echo = Flow[ByteString]
      .via(Framing.delimiter(
        ByteString("\n"),
        maximumFrameLength = 256,
        allowTruncation = true))
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .map(_ + "!!!\n")
      .map(ByteString(_))

    connection.handleWith(echo)
  }
```

How would you change the example so that you could *also* get a hold of the `Future[ServerBinding]` so that you could log successful binding and handle binding errors if, for example, the port were already in use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get this by moving away from the convenience of `runForeach` which hides the details of the `Sink` involved and instead use an explicit `Sink`.  Something like this:

```
  val host = "localhost"
  val port = 4444
  val connections: Source[IncomingConnection, Future[ServerBinding]] =
    Tcp().bind(host, port)


  val sink = Sink.foreach[IncomingConnection]{ connection =>
    println(s"New connection from: ${connection.remoteAddress}")

    val echo = Flow[ByteString]
      .via(Framing.delimiter(
        ByteString("\n"),
        maximumFrameLength = 256,
        allowTruncation = true))
      .map(_.utf8String)
      .map(_ + "!!!\n")
      .map(ByteString(_))

    connection.handleWith(echo)    
  }

  val serverBinding:Future[ServerBinding] = connections.to(sink).run
```